# react-native-background-fetch never execute the callback function

Tags: android, react-native, background-task, react-native-background-fetch

For android
I created startStask function to start my background task with BackgroundFetch from 'react-native-background-fetch' like this :

```
const startStask = async () => {
  try {
    console.log('try ok');
    await BackgroundFetch.configure(
      {
        minimumFetchInterval: 15, 
        stopOnTerminate: true, 
        startOnBoot: true, 
      },
      async taskId => {
        console.log('[BackgroundFetch] taskId: ', taskId);

        await locationAndNotificationTask();

        BackgroundFetch.finish(taskId);
      },
      error => {
        console.log('[BackgroundFetch] failed to start');
      },
    );
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('start BG stask err', error);
  }
};
```

But the call back is never called (no logs after "try ok") and locationAndNotificationTask is not called.
This fonction is call with a toggle action like that :

```
const toggleSwitch = async () => {
    const newValue = !isEnabled;
    try {
      console.log('okay ! ', newValue)
      if (newValue) {
        setIsEnabled(newValue); // true
        await AsyncStorage.setItem('notifications_status', `${newValue}`);
        backgroundTaskIsRunning() ? null : await startStask();
      } else {
        setIsEnabled(newValue); // false
        await AsyncStorage.setItem('notifications_status', `${newValue}`);
        await stopStask();
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('menuScreen err', error);
    }
  };
```

- React-native 0.73.2
- minSdkVersion = 21
- compileSdkVersion = 34
- targetSdkVersion = 34
- react-native-background-fetch: "^4.2.1",

thanks.